# Adding a custom attribute to a type created using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have created a type and with few properties and assigned values to those properties. I need to bind this class with a property grid. I need to add/decorate custom attribute to some of the properties i have created using reflection.

Could some one help me adding a custom attribute using reflection.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(DropDownConverter))]
        public string NAME
        {
            get { return m_name; }
            set
            {
                m_name = value;
            }
        }
```

Finally the property should  have a TypeConverter attribute added to it.

Thanks,
Kishore Borra.

Comment: What do you mean "some of the properties" you have created using reflection?  Do you mean you are using `Reflection.Emit`?

Comment: Yes i have created the type and all its properties using reflection. I have used Reflection.Emit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and implement `GetProperties` to return custom `PropertyDescriptor`s that contain you attributes.